# unable to acquire token for tenant organizations in Azure DevOps Release pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

How must we configure Azure to allow a Release Pipeline to execute a power shell script?

Currently hitting this error:

```
2023-09-20T10:20:59.8639269Z ##[error]ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. 
The requested identity has not been assigned to this resource.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
```

The Release Pipeline is trying to do the following:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Stop Triggers'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Name (<<guid>>)'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_adf_master_source/ci-cd.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_adf_publish_source/<<projectname>>/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName "<<resource group name>>" -DataFactoryName "<<data factory name>>" -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    pwsh: true
```